# React child component doesn't re-render when parent state changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a React stateful component to process text inputted in a textbox, and to save and load text between a database and the textbox. I can type in the textbox, and I can save what's in the textbox to my database. When I load from the database to the textbox, my component's state updates, and the (child) textbox's prop which handles passing text from the parent component to the textbox updates according to React DevTools in Chrome. The problem is that the value of the textbox is not re-rendered to reflect the new prop.

I did some research, and I found that React components are supposed to re-render whenever the state changes. I tried adding state to the child component using `useState()`, and I update the state every time the props change using

```
useEffect(() => setText(propText), [propText])
```

It didn't work. The props and state in React DevTools show the value I loaded in, but the component doesn't show it in the textbox. Maybe it isn't designed to get its input value from props and state as opposed to a user typing, but its onChange() event handler updates the parent state like I'm trying to do with the database access component, so it's completely abstracted.

Here's the child component as it stands right now:

```
function InputTextComponent(props) {
  const { parentInput, textUpdate } = props;
  const [text, setText] = useState(parentInput);
  useEffect(() => setText(parentInput), [parentInput]);

  const onTextChange = event => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    textUpdate(value);
  };
  return (
    <TextAreaGroup
      placeholder={'Input text'}
      name={'Input text here'}
      value={text}
      info={'Input text'}
      onChange={event => onTextChange(event)}
    />
  );
}
```

Here's the parent component:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textInput: '',
    };
    this.textUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  textUpdate = textInput => this.setState({ textInput });

  render() {
    const {
      textInput,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <InputTextComponent
          textUpdate={this.textUpdate}
          parentInput={textInput}
        />

        <LoadTextsComponent
          alias={alias} // alias is irrelevant part of the component
          aliasUpdate={this.aliasUpdate}
          skuUpdate={this.skuUpdate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The database load component uses the `textUpdate()` function. Here's the full component:

```
function LoadTextsComponent(props) {
  const { alias, aliasUpdate, textUpdate } = props;
  const [setList, setListUpdate] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await client.get('/texts/listTexts');
      aliasUpdate(result[0].alias);
      setListUpdate(result);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const loadTextsToInputBox = () => {
    let aliasSet;
    for (let set of setList) {
      if (set.alias === alias) {
        aliasSet = set.texts;
      }
    }
    let textString = '';
    for (let text of aliasSet) {
      textString += text + '\n';
    }
    textString = textString.slice(0, -1);
    textUpdate(textString);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ShowAliasesComponent
        setList={setList}
        alias={alias}
        aliasUpdate={aliasUpdate}
      />

      <button
        disabled={!alias}
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={() => loadTextsToInputBox()}
      >
        Send texts of alias {alias} to input box
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What's really confusing is when I type in the child textbox, the parent state updates correctly (passing down a function to update parent state) and the new prop is reflected in the render. But, when I call that same function from the database load component, nothing happens.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Sorry but this code is not enough for us to help you. Please share where the component is rendered and all of the valuable code. I _think_ you are using an uncontrolled component, but we can say without seeing the code

Comment: I added what I think is important, let me know if you think there's something missing

Comment: why are using hooks inside InputTextComponent? you already have value in parentInput.

Comment: Why do you need local state in `InputTextComponent`? It looks like the input is fully controlled by the outer component. Duplicating state is an anti-pattern.

Comment: `But, when I call that same function from the database load component, nothing happens.` how are you calling it?

Comment: So I originally didn't duplicate state, and it had the same effect as I described above--it worked for keyboard input but not for database input. I read that react components only rerender on state change, so I'm trying to be very explicit. It didn't help, though. If it ends up not adding anything useful, I'm going to return it back to the props-only version.

Comment: @Clarity same way as in the textbox component, I pass down the `textUpdate` function as a prop and call the function once I have my text from the database. DevTools shows the text making it to the component's props, just not the value rendered.

Comment: @NickSchmeller can you show the code?

Comment: How are you actually communicating with this database? From the code you provided, nothing actually suggests that you are getting data/updating data from/to a database?

Comment: Provided code works even with `useState` and `useEffect`. See here https://codesandbox.io/s/so57141226-dh38i-dh38i. So your problem in some other part of program

Comment: @ChristopherNgo the expected text from the database shows up in DevTools (in props), just not what's actually rendered

Comment: Can you verify with console.log that when you call `textUpdate(textString);` from `loadTextsToInputBox`, `textString` actually has a string?

Comment: @Clarity yes, in `loadTextsToInputBox`, `console.log(textString)` appended to the end of the function prints the expected text in the console

Comment: Can you change your useEffect to this in the `InputTextComponent`: `useEffect(() =>  { setText(parentInput) }, [parentInput]);` (note the braces).

Comment: @Clarity nothing changed in render or DevTools

Comment: @NickSchmeller I replicated you code in code sandbox and it works, maybe you need to use `LoadTextsComponent` instead of `LoadSkusComponent`?

Comment: @Clarity my apologies, it should have been `LoadTextsComponent`. Do you have the code sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-example-kd37v, just make sure React is 16.8.0 in the package.json

Comment: @Clarity thank you, you showed me exactly what I was doing wrong -- you use a `<textarea>`, whereas I was using a wrapper component called `<TextAreaGroup>`, which I'm finding out has some unexpected behavior when it comes to rendering